# How to add tags to Autocomplete Tag-it plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, tag-it

I want to add new tags to the variable 'sampleTags' in the following code

```
 $(function () {
        var sampleTags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby',     'python', 'c', 'scala', 'groovy', 'haskell', 'perl', 'erlang', 'apl', 'cobol', 'go', 'lua'];
         $('#singleFieldTags2').tagit({
             availableTags: sampleTags
         });
    });
```

I have tags available as string or JSONResult data type,but iam unable to add them to it.
I am new to this AJAX kind of stuff,so if it sounds silly,don't mind.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
            var sampleTags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby',     'python', 'c', 'scala', 'groovy', 'haskell', 'perl', 'erlang', 'apl', 'cobol', 'go', 'lua'];
             $('#singleFieldTags2').tagit({
                 itemName: 'item',
                 fieldName: 'tags',
                 availableTags: sampleTags

             });
        });
```

It's working perfect for me. Setting autocomplete.source to make it understand.